# Multiple SVN Repositories

Tags: svn

The SVN 1.6.12 repository, we'll call it `A`, I have been using for a while has the following layout:

```
<A>
    tool1/
        branches/
        tags/
            v1/
                dirs and files...
            v2/
                dirs and files...
        trunk/
    tool2/
        branches/
        ...
```

I created a second repository, we'll call `B`, on the same server.  Its structure needs to be...

```
<B>
    tool1/
        dirs and files...
    tool2/
        dirs and files...
```

The contents of `B`'s tool1 would be that of `A`'s tool1/tags/v2.  `B`'s tool2 would be that of `A`'s tool2/tags/v2.

How the two repos should be used is that when code is commited to `A`'s tool1/tags/v2 it is commited to `B`'s tool1/tags/v2 as well... I wrote a `pre-commit` hook for `B` which needs to run.  I don't want to have to check code into `A` and check out, modify and commit on `B` separately.  Is this possible?  Maybe SVN's `externals` will do the trick?  If not I am accepting of suggestions.

Maybe `externals` won't support my use case.  I read the Red Bean `svnsync` reference and determined, though it seems that would certainly do what I need, I don't want to store authentication info in a script nor do I know if the `pre-commit` would run when syncing.

Comment: Why do you need two repositories with the same content arranged differently in the first place? What problem are you attempting to solve by doing this?

Comment: @alroc: The entirety of `B` is not the same as `A`... only tags/v2 of each tool exists in `B`.  The reason there are two repos is that `A` needs no pre-commit hook whereas `B` does.

Comment: Started some testing with `externals`.  The `pre-commit` hook runs on the external repo.  This is a start though I still have to add the desired files in `A` into `A`/my_external_dir for them to journey into `B`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `svn:externals` works but not as smoothly as I'd like.  `A`'s structure turns out to be...

```
<A>
    tool1/
        branches/
        tags/
            v1/
            v2/ ( <-- svn:externals pointing to <B>/tool1 )
        trunk/
    tool2/
        ...
        tags/
            v1/
            v2/ ( <-- svn:externals pointing to <B>/tool2 )
        ...
```

...then `B`...

```
<B>
    tool1/
    tool2/
```

`B`'s pre-commit hook runs when committing `A/toolX/v2` (which is an important requirement).

FYI.